# WordPress - move blog from root to subdirectory

Tags: wordpress

I have genesis template of WordPress and I have there a blog  x.com/blog

but now I created a folder blog - subdirectory with new WordPress installation  in the root and I want  the the sit : x.com/blog will work with the new blog. new WordPress site /installation  -- the homepage works but all the category and posts redirected to the old one

I try to add rules to htaccess and i tried to add "blog"  to index php before the blog-template.php  in index php - it is working but the old site now is not works at all.

so how can I do that  ?

thx

Comment: It sounds like you have one WordPress install and you want to move it from root to `/blog`? Or do you have two installs?

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you have one WordPress install and you want to move it from root to `/blog`? Or do you have two installs?

If you have one install, you need to move the original `.htaccess` file and move and edit the `index.php` file, as well as save permalinks once you've complete the move.

The complete instructions from https://codex.wordpress.org/Giving_WordPress_Its_Own_Directory#Moving_a_Root_install_to_its_own_directory :

> 1) In Settings, change the box for WordPress address (URL): change the
>   address to the new location of your main WordPress core files.
>   Example: http://example.com/wordpress
>
> 2) In the box for Site address (URL): change the address to the root
>   directory's URL. Example: http://example.com
>
> 3) Save Changes. (Do not worry about the error message and do not try
>   to see your blog at this point! You will probably get a message about
>   file not found.)
>
> 4) Move your WordPress core files to the new location (WordPress
>   address).
>
> 5) Copy (NOT MOVE!) the index.php and .htaccess files from the
>   WordPress directory into the root directory of your site (Blog
>   address). The .htaccess file is invisible, so you may have to set your
>   FTP client to show hidden files. If you are not using pretty
>   permalinks, then you may not have a .htaccess file.
>
> (If you are running WordPress on a Windows (IIS) server and are using
>   pretty permalinks, you'll have a web.config rather than a .htaccess
>   file in your WordPress directory. For the index.php file the
>   instructions remain the same, copy (don't move) the index.php file to
>   your root directory. The web.config file, must be treated differently
>   than the .htaccess file so you must MOVE (DON'T COPY) the web.config
>   file to your root directory.)
>
> 6) Open your root directory's index.php file in a text editor
>
> 7) Change the following and save the file. Change the line that says:
>   `require( dirname( __FILE__ ) . '/wp-blog-header.php' );` to the
>   following, using your directory name for the WordPress core files:
>   `require( dirname( __FILE__ ) . '/wordpress/wp-blog-header.php' );`
>   Login to the new location. It might now be
>   http://example.com/wordpress/wp-admin/
>
> 8) If you have set up Permalinks, go to the Permalinks panel and
>   update your Permalink structure. WordPress will automatically update
>   your .htaccess file if it has the appropriate file permissions. If
>   WordPress can't write to your .htaccess file, it will display the new
>   rewrite rules to you, which you should manually copy into your
>   .htaccess file

Comment: If you want to use the main domain for some static html pages, then don't do the index.php changes, just move it to /blog folder.

Answer (score 0):

This is a simple move but it seems to work 70% of the time:

Go to Dashboard -> Settings -> Permalinks

Go down to the bottom and click "save".

WordPress will regenerate your links.

If this doesn't work then try a plugin that regenerates links.